# Extract data from Query

Tags: sql, vb.net, ms-access

Can you please teach me on how to extract data from SQL query access database and place it into a Variable holder? I've been struggling for a week already and i've been really trying hard, please advise Thanks

This is what i have done so far :

```
Imports System.Data.OleDb
Public Class ModifyForm
    Dim connstring As String = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0; Data Source= c:\Databse\Company_db.accdb"
    Dim conn As New OleDbConnection
    Private Sub MainMenuButton_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MainMenuButton.Click
        Me.Close()
        Form1.Show()

    End Sub

    Private Sub CloseButton_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles CloseButton.Click
        Me.Close()
        Form1.Close()

    End Sub

    Private Sub DeleteBut_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles DeleteBut.Click

    End Sub

    Private Sub ModifyForm_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        'TODO: This line of code loads data into the "Company_dbDataSet1.tbl_empinfo" table. You can move, or remove it, as needed.'
        Me.Tbl_empinfoTableAdapter.Fill(Me.Company_dbDataSet1.tbl_empinfo)

    End Sub
    Private Sub eNumText_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles eNumText.SelectedIndexChanged

        Dim empNum As String
        Dim empFname As String
        Dim empLname As String
        Dim empDept As String
        Dim empStat As String
        Dim empYears As String

        empNum = eNumText.Text
        empFname = empFnameText.Text
        empLname = empLnameText.Text
        empDept = DeptText.Text
        empStat = StatText.Text
        empYears = yearstext.Text

        MsgBox(empNum)
        Dim conn As New OleDbConnection
        conn.Open()


        Dim SqlQuerry As String = "SELECT * FROM tbl_empinfo WHERE EmpID like empNum"
        Dim SqlCommand As New OleDbCommand
        Dim SqlAdapter As New OleDbDataAdapter
        Dim Table As New DataTable

        With SqlCommand
            .CommandText = SqlQuerry
            .Connection = conn

        End With

        With SqlAdapter
            .SelectCommand = SqlCommand
            .Fill(Table)


        End With

        DataGridView1.Rows.Clear()
        For i = 0 To Table.Rows.Count - 1
            With DataGridView1
                .Rows.Add(Table.Rows(i)("EmpID"), (Table.Rows(i)("FirstName")))
            End With

        Next

        'Dim dbSource = "Data Source= C:\Databse\Company_db.accdb"'


        conn.Close()

    End Sub
```

Comment: You're butchering it I'm afraid.  You're writing a whole load of code that you shouldn't be.  You obviously already have a Data Source and you've dragged your `tbl_empinfo` onto the form so get rid of all that other data access code.  The designer has already generated all the code you need to retrieve the data from the database and display it in the UI.  You have a DataSet and a table adapter and the code in your Load event handler is using the latter to populate the former.  That DataSet will be bound to a BindingSource and that will be bound to a DataGridView or a set of TextBoxes, etc.

Comment: @har07 How do i get the Emp ID and FirstName from my SQL Query and store them to Variable empID and empFname? I really want to learn to extract the data and place it into a variable? Please teach me :(

Answer (score 1):

Forgetting about the extra code, as was mentioned already, all you need to do is declare your variables:

```
Dim DBID As Integer  ' Or whatever type you're using for the ID field
Dim DBFirstName As String
```

Then inside the For/Next loop, just use:

```
DBID = Table.Rows(i)("EmpID")
DBFirstName = Table.Rows(i)("FirstName")
```

That is only if you're going to use the variables within the for/next loop, otherwise you'll be overwriting them for every record.  If you need to store all the values, you'll have to use arrays instead.